# SonarLint for Eclipse cannot bind project: can return only the first 10000 results

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint-eclipse

Unable to update data from server 
'**sonarqube server url**'
Error 400 on
**sonarqube server url**/api/rules/search.protobuf?f=repo,name,severity,lang,htmlDesc,htmlNote,internalKey,isTemplate,templateKey,actives&statuses=BETA,DEPRECATED,READY&p=21&ps=500: Can return only the first 10000 results. 10500th result asked.

Comment: What about the error message is unclear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SonarLint cannot download full components list because you have too many of them. It could occur when you use Community Edition and scan all branches of your projects. You have 3 options:

- buy at least Developer edition which keeps all branches together and reduces the number of components
- delete automatically projects which wasn't analyzed for last X days (old branches)
- you can manually set the key of the project (this error blocks the possibility to bind projects automatically, but you still can do it by your own)